# DAX : Find process time & last operation from date/time difference

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

Need your help to find "Process Time" in hours and where it in last operation based on Max Operation number

```html
DATEDIFF(
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(tableX[date/time]),
        ALLEXCEPT(tableX,tableX[Operation],tableX[ID]),
        tableX[date/time] <= EARLIER(tableX[date/time])
   ), 
   tableX[date/time],HOUR
)
```

[image: capture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the following calculated column:

```
Process Time (Hours) = DATEDIFF(
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('tableX'[Date/Time]),
        ALLEXCEPT(tableX,'tableX'[ID]),
        'tableX'[date/time] < EARLIER('tableX'[date/time])
   ), 
   'tableX'[Date/Time],HOUR
)
```

This expression calculates the elapsed time sinds the previous step in the operation. If you want to calculate the elapsed time sinds the start of the operation, then simply change `MAX('tableX'[Date/Time])` to `MIN('tableX'[Date/Time])`. Like this:

[image]

To create the last column, you can use this:

```
Last Operation =
IF (
    'tableX'[Date/Time]
        = CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'tableX'[Date/Time] ), ALLEXCEPT ( 'tableX', tableX[ID] ) ),
    "Y",
    "N"
)
```

Comment: Ah it works perfectly !!! thank you and wondering if you could answer for the 2nd question how to create new model to mark last operation for example 30 should be the last operation for wall and and 40 for floor .

Comment: I presume you mean the other column in your example. (See my edit).  If not, what do you mean with "40 for floor" ?